# AbstractProvider error when creating custom driver for SSO via Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm on Laravel v8.65 and running Socialite v5.9.

I am trying to allow users of my application to login via SSO. The identity provider is a third-party CRM. The CRM is not natively supported by Socialite, so I am creating a custom driver. I followed the steps [outlined in this post](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-socialite-custom-driver), but I am hitting an error:

```
 Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider::__construct(): Argument #1 ($reques  
  t) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, Illuminate\Foundation\Applicati  
  on given, called in /Users/m/Documents/websites/a/vendo  
  r/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on lin  
  e 208
```

Below is the content of the ServiceProvider file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
class NoviServiceProvider extends AbstractProvider
{
    /**
    * @var string[]
    */
    protected $scopes = [
        'openid',
        'profile',
    ];
 
    /**
    * @var string
    */
    protected $scopeSeparator = ' ';
 

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    /**
     * @throws BindingResolutionException
     */


    public function getNoviUrl()
    {
        return config('services.novi.base_uri') . '/oauth';
    }
 
    /**
     * @param string $state
     *
     * @return string
     */

    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase($this->getNoviUrl() . '/authorize', $state);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
 
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return $this->getCognitoUrl() . '/token';
    }

    /**
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @throws GuzzleException
     *
     * @return array|mixed
     */
 
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->post($this->getNoviUrl() . '/userInfo', [
            'headers' => [
                'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
        ]);
     
        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
 
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id' => $user['sub'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
            'username' => $user['username'],
            'email_verified' => $user['email_verified'],
            'family_name' => $user['family_name'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

My `AppServiceProvider.php` file with the updated `boot()`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $socialite = $this->app->make(Factory::class);
     
        $socialite->extend('novi', function () use ($socialite) {
        $config = config('services.novi');
     
            return $socialite->buildProvider(NoviServiceProvider::class, $config);
        });
    }
}
```

How can I get around this error?

I have tried a variety of solutions online, but the articles are dated back to 2015 or 2018:

Attempts include changing class declaration to:

`class NoviServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements ProviderInterface`

Comment: Remove code from ServiceProvider and check how work this (for example) https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Cognito/blob/master/CognitoExtendSocialite.php

Comment: @Maksim I installed this and made some tweaks. It worked flawlessly. Thank you. How can I give credit?